# Convert 2d list to datetime in Python and then plot

Tags: python, string, list, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a giant 2D list of  string dates onto an x axis but there are too many ticks.

Here is a shortened example of the list

```
[['2021-10-01 10:25:42 PM','2021-10-01 10:31:13 PM' '2021-10-01 10:31:13 PM'],['2021-10-01 10:25:42 PM','2021-10-01 10:31:13 PM' '2021-10-01 10:31:13 PM']]
```

I want to convert this list to datetime object so I can reduce these tick marks.

I am not sure how I can do this on a 2-D list.

For example this is not working because it is on a list.

```
dates_list = [datetime.strptime(date, '"%Y-%m-%d"').date() for date in valueTime_list]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't apply `strptime` to a list, you have to go through the nested lists in a second loop.
Besides some commas are missing in your initial `valueTime_list` and the `format` for `strptime` has to match the one of the lists:

```
from datetime import datetime
valueTime_list = [['2021-10-01 10:25:42 PM','2021-10-01 10:31:13 PM', '2021-10-01 10:31:13 PM'],['2021-10-01 10:25:42 PM','2021-10-01 10:31:13 PM', '2021-10-01 10:31:13 PM']]

dates_list = [datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p').date()
              for date_lst in valueTime_list for date in date_lst]
print(dates_list)
```

Output:

```
[datetime.date(2021, 10, 1), datetime.date(2021, 10, 1), datetime.date(2021, 10, 1), datetime.date(2021, 10, 1), datetime.date(2021, 10, 1), datetime.date(2021, 10, 1)]
```

Edit: if you wanna keep the 2-d structure, add brackets to your comprehension:

```
dates_list = [[datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p').date() for date in date_lst]
              for date_lst in valueTime_list]
```

Comment: Hi thank you but I realized that this way does not maintain the 2D list structure as when I went to plot, the dimensions were mismatched. I did not mention i wanted the structure to be maintained though.

Comment: sure, you just need some more brackets in the list comprehension. I updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `pandas`, you can use `pd.to_datetime` converter:

```py
dates_list = [pd.to_datetime(lst, infer_datetime_format=True) for lst in valueTime_list]
```

This will result in the same 2D list with `DateTimeIndex` objects (Series of datetime object).